# Laravel - belongsToMany relationship timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I have a pivot table called `thread_user` and I have two models; User.php and Thread.php.

I have this in my User.php file:

```
public function threads()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Thread')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

I only want the created_at timestamp though. I don't want updated_at and every time I try to attach something to the pivot table, I get this error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'...`. It is really annoying. I can't have the `updated_at` timestamp for some reason but I still do want the `created_at` timestamp.

Please let me know how I can fix this. I have tried the following with no luck:

`return $this->belongsToMany('App\Thread')->withTimestamps(['created_at']);`

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not using both timestamps, you need to remove the call to `withTimestamps()` and just call `withPivot()` for the field that you do have.

So, your code should look like:

```
public function threads()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Thread')->withPivot('created_at');
}
```